# Filtering odd numbers

Tags: python, list-comprehension, modulo

```
M = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]

col2 = [row[1] + 1 for row in M if row[1] % 2 == 0]
print (col2)
```

Output: `[3, 9]`

I'm expecting it to filter out the odd numbers, but it does the opposite.

Comment: Would help if you posted your intended output in future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is doing exactly what you would expect - if the second item is even, increase it by one and put it into the list.

So for the first row, it sees that 2 % 2 == 0 is True, and sets col2[0] = 2 + 1 = 3. For the second row, 5 % 2 == 0 is False. For the third row, 8%2 == 0 is True, and col2[1] = 8 + 1 = 9.

Comment: Oh, so it reads the IF statement first? I thought statements were processed left-t-right?

Comment: Yes - list comprehensions allow multiple conditions after the for loop, and the expression on the left is evaluated after considering all of those conditions. (technical explanation: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to switch the comparison to `== 1` from `== 0`.

The modulus of any number divided by 2 is 0 or 1, 1 when it is odd.

Comment: Hmm..not really. I tried this: for n in range(10): n = n % 2 and it printed ODD as '0'

Answer (score 0):

You are testing `row[1]%2`, but printing `row[1]+1`
so when `row[1]==2`, it is even, but you are appending `3` to the result
when `row[1]==5`, it is odd, so you filter it out
and when `row[1]==8`, it is even, but you are appending `9` to the result

Answer (score 0):

```
M = [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]]
col2 = []

for row in M:
    if row[1]%2 == 1:
        col2.append(row[1])
print col2
```